# Applying multiple functions to one column

Tags: r, function, dataframe, sapply

I have four functions, clean, clean2, cleanFun, and trim. Currently I apply the functions to one column, like so.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)


py17$CE.Finding.Description <- clean(py17$CE.Finding.Description)
py17$CE.Finding.Description  <- clean2(py17$CE.Finding.Description)
py17$CE.Finding.Description  <- cleanFun(py17$CE.Finding.Description)
py17$CE.Finding.Description  <- trim(py17$CE.Finding.Description)
```

This process does the trick but I have to copy and paste this multiple times, and I'd eventually like to expand this to multiple columns.

For now, I'd like to save time and add an apply function but I'm not sure how to create that apply function. I've tried creating this.

```
maxclean <- function(cleaner) {
                c(clean(cleaner), clean2(cleaner), cleanFun(cleaner), trim(cleaner))
                 }


py17$CE.Finding.Description <- sapply(py17$CE.Finding.Description, maxclean)
```

After trying this I just get

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, CE.Finding.Description, value = c(NA,  : 
  replacement has 4 rows, data has 4318
```

I do not get any errors doing this the long way. Where am I going wrong on this?

Comment: Why not aggregate the functionality into a single function?

Comment: Why do you include `library(data.table)` and `library(tidyverse)` in your question, but apparently not use either?

Comment: @Gregor I thought I'd use it just in case someone may know a faster way with either library. I'll be sure to not mention the libraries next time, thanks though.

Comment: In a case like that, I'd just put in the text "Open to solutions using `data.table` or tidyverse." That gets the message across nicely without implying that you are (or think you are) using them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `maxclean` function should take the same arguments as the separate functions. In your case - a vector. And then call each function in a row. Like this:

```
maxclean <- function(x) {
            x <- clean(x)
            x <- clean2(x)
            x <- cleanFun(x)
            x <- trim(x)
            return(x)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the OP has created a cleaning pipeline where the output of one step is fed into the next step and the final result of the pipeline overwrites the original input.

The `magrittr` package has the `freduce()` function which applies one function after the other in the described way. Thus,

```
py17$CE.Finding.Description <- clean(py17$CE.Finding.Description)
py17$CE.Finding.Description  <- clean2(py17$CE.Finding.Description)
py17$CE.Finding.Description  <- cleanFun(py17$CE.Finding.Description)
py17$CE.Finding.Description  <- trim(py17$CE.Finding.Description)
```

can be written as:

```
library(magrittr)
fcts <- list(clean, clean2, cleanFun, trim)
py17$CE.Finding.Description %<>% freduce(fcts)
```

which is a shortcut for

```
py17$CE.Finding.Description <- py17$CE.Finding.Description %>% 
  clean() %>% 
  clean2() %>% 
  cleanFun() %>% 
  trim()
```

Here, `%>%` is the magrittr forward-pipe operator and `%<>%` is the magrittr compound assignment pipe-operator which updates the left-hand side object with the resulting value.

#### Reproducible example

Using the `mtcars` dataset:

```
data(mtcars)
mycars <- mtcars
mycars$mpg %<>% 
  {. - mean(.)} %>% 
  abs() %>% 
  sqrt()
mycars
```

or

```
mycars <- mtcars
mycars$mpg %<>% freduce(list(function(.) {. - mean(.)}, abs, sqrt))
mycars
```

#### Applying on multiple columns

The OP has mentioned that he *eventually like to expand this to multiple columns*

This can be achieved by, e.g.,

```
mycars <- mtcars
fcts <- list(function(.) {. - mean(.)}, abs, sqrt)
mycars$mpg %<>% freduce(fcts)
mycars$disp %<>% freduce(fcts)
mycars
```